# 22 posts for review missing...

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I just cleared all visible review tasks, but still the review notification cries

$\hskip2in$ "~22 posts awaiting review"

Does "~" mean that the service is just too slow to, or what? Or is it meant as a crude approximation?

[image]

Comment: To see where the "missing" items are (at least most of them) go to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/review while *not* logged in.

Comment: ... ignore the *meta* part of the link.

Comment: And yes, $~\sim x$ means it's an approximation.  The actual number of reviews is $x(\pm x)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233535). My solution is to hide the distracting orange light with user CSS, and instead use a [bookmarklet](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/instant-showing-of-review-tasks/13877#13877) that shows current review count in the tab name of the review page.