# Empty queues are not empty...sometimes!

Tags: bug, review

I think I saw the message:

> This queue has been cleared!...

for the first time today. For fun, I clicked on another queue with 0 pending review tasks and surprisingly found one. I tried some other queues with a mixed overall result: Some empty queues are empty, some are not. [Wanna try?](https://math.stackexchange.com/review)

Is this [another case](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16299/19341) of  [status-bydesign](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or do these tasks just materialize during the time loading the review page and clicking on the specific queue?

Comment: I am willing to bet it is just "tasks materialize during the time loading the review page and clicking on the specific queue". This website is [huge](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Comment: @WillieWong But refreshing the review page doesn't indicate any activity, which would imply that also the community is huge. So huge that tasks emerge and vanish in a time on the Planck scale... really? Further there is currently a mean of 3 Close tasks in the review queue...

Comment: really. Even on MathOverflow there has been times when I entered a queue with x items and the queue empties after I've only reviewed x - y items. Both x, y > 0. Over here if there are three of four people obsessively clicking on the review queues (like you? `:-)`) then I wouldn't be surprised at all.

Comment: I don't know if you have enough rep to access the review queues on other sites, but if you do, try it on a smaller site. If it is a bug then the software being the same the bug will also show on the smaller sites. If it is a timing issue the smaller sites would be much more "stable". (For example, I just tried and cannot reproduce on MO.)

Comment: @WillieWong ok it looks different on a smaller site. But I would expect the non-zero value would vary faster on non-stable sites...

Comment: @WillieWong I continued clicking on empty queues and got the impression that review-audits are more frequent then. Further I had two suggested-edits in a row on the empty queue. I'm tending to disagree with your "huge-website" argument towards my bug assumption...

Comment: "I continued clicking on empty queues and got the impression that review-audits are more frequent then." And you are surprised why? I think you are doing a fine job passing the reverse Turing test `:-)`.

Comment: @WillieWong "You [I] passed" [again](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/267608). Are there statistics on my audits, showing my progress towards the full acceptance in the robot community?